# Check if screen is narrow

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-orientation

I have an activity configured with `splitActionBarWhenNarrow` that uses `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY)`.

And I need to check if screen is considered narrow to know if splitbar is visible because I have to  change the position of one bottom component to don't overlap with splitActionbar when visible.

PD: I know how to check orientation but I'm not sure if *portrait* is always equal to *narrow*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By checking the ActionBarSherlock sources I've found a solution that seems to work very well: Create a `values.xml` in your `values` resource directory and add a new boolean property like this:

```
<resources>
    <bool name="screen_is_narrow">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Then create a second `values.xml` in the `values-w480dp` directory:

```
<resources>
    <bool name="screen_is_narrow">false</bool>
</resources>
```

This second resource will automatically be loaded if the screen is wider than 480dp. In portrait mode your phone screen is smaller than that so `screen_is_narrow` is `true` whereas in landscape mode and on tablets it is wider and thus `screen_is_narrow` becomes `false`.

Based on that logic you can simply do a check in your Activity code now:

```
boolean screenIsNarrow = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.screen_is_narrow);
```

That should do the trick. In case you're already using ActionBarSherlock then there's an even easier solution as the booleans have been predefined already. Simply check for `R.bool.abs__split_action_bar_is_narrow` in your code.

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't. The logic is independent from any libraries but utilizes a platform feature: loading resources (xml) depending on the device configuration (e.g. screen size). The boolean is used to determine the size programmatically. But you can load all kind of resources such as graphics, layouts, and even colors the same way.

Comment: It would be nice to override some of AppCompat's value.xml files